# Does access modifier plays role in Overring method in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am learning typescript and came from a Java, and C++ background. Some of the stuff is a bit confusing.

I was researching Inheritance in TypeScript and found this on Chatgpt and Bard.

**In  TypeScript, if you use an access modifier when declaring a property or method in a derived class, you are indicating that you are overriding a member of the base class. If you do not use an access modifier, TypeScript will assume that you are introducing a new member in the derived class with the same name but not overriding the member of the base class.**

That means **hashSecretValue** method is not said to be overridden as we have not explicitly mentioned access modifiers. But that doesn't make sense right since it is overriding the base class method.

```js
class Sports {
    
    private nameSports: string
    protected numPlayers: number

    constructor(
        nameSports: string,
        numPlayers: number
    ) {
        this.nameSports = nameSports 
        this.numPlayers = numPlayers
    }

    private giveSecretValue(): string {
        return "secret value"
    }

    public hashSecretValue(): string {
        return this.giveSecretValue + " hashed"
    }
}

class Cricket extends Sports{

    constructor(
        nameSports: string,
        public numPlayers: number
    ) {
        super(nameSports, numPlayers)
    }

    override hashSecretValue(param?: number):string {
        return 'overidden hashSecretValue method'
    }
}
```

Comment: ChatGPT is, as is often the case, incorrect.

Comment: Circling back to this, how should we proceed with this question?  You got bad information from ChatGPT/Bard.  Should we write an answer saying that?  I suppose we could write "access modifiers do not affect whether or not a method is overridden; they are simply erased from the emitted JavaScript and cannot possibly have such an effect".  Would that suffice here or are you looking for something else?